# MyGeneration command line input

Tags: mygeneration

I have looked all over the internet, mygenteration's forum, and mygenteration's  website and I cannot figure out how to pass parameters into a template through the command line using the xmldatapath switch. Does anyone know how to do this?

--edit--

I did a little research and [here is a summary of the format of xml input for MyGeneration](http://williamsmash.com/blog/show/mygeneration-xml-input-format).

Comment: Jumped to your blog and saw that you answered your own question, I don't have the rep to edit your question, could you do it. Nice to see someone else use MyGeneration - do you reckon it could be used to create Xaml from DB ?

Comment: @MrTelly thanks for the suggestion. Also I think it would be a great way to create some custom xaml. I never thought of that before but after reading your idea, I think there could be some interesting possibilities with that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [this post](http://community.entityspaces.net/forums/thread/10816.aspx), which indicates that the `-i xmldatapath` works with a saved output file created by MyGeneration itself. You don't detail what your exact issue is, have you tried using -c to create the file that you then use with -i? If you're still having issues add some more detail and I'll run up MyGeneration from the source and see what's going on.